# android global hotkey

Tags: android

How to start your activity on pressing a global hotkey on android?
It is possible, see Button Shortcut app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the 'search' button:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the archive:

This (alone) does not help:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
```

```
<activity android:name=".VoiceActions"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
          <!-- This must be higher than the default priority (0), which
         is what GoogleSearch uses. -->
    <intent-filter android:priority="500">
        <action android:name="android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>


          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" /> 

    </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".VoiceActions" />
</application>
```